# how to create upload file to Google Drive in Android App

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have implement a function upload file to Google Drive. My app (Android App) have two page.

**Setting Page**: we have config the google account. After login in to google account. We grant the right and save the OAUTH_TOKEN and OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET to the *SharedPreferences*.

**Upload page**: We choose files from explorer. Then click on button [UPLOAD] to send them Google Drive.

I found the sample code on developers.google.com show how to upload file. It look like this

---

```
/**
   * Insert new file.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
   * @param description Description of the file to insert.
   * @param parentId Optional parent folder's ID.
   * @param mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
   * @param filename Filename of the file to insert.
   * @return Inserted file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String description,
      String parentId, String mimeType, String filename) {
    // File's metadata.
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(title);
    body.setDescription(description);
    body.setMimeType(mimeType);

    // Set the parent folder.
    if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
      body.setParents(
          Arrays.asList(new File.ParentReference().setId(parentId));
    }

    // File's content.
    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);
    try {
      File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

      // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
      // System.out.println("File ID: %s" + file.getId());

      return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

---

So we just call above function to upload the file. But i don't know how to initialize the 
Drive *(com.google.api.services.drive.Drive)* to pass to the function.

What thing i have to do to initialize the drive variable with OAUTH_TOKEN and OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET ?

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: How to initialize service in that method,how i can save the autentication

Comment: Hi, @quantm, did you got answer for this?, could you upload file to Google Drive in Android App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth 2.0 page in the Google Drive SDK documentation explains how to retrieve valid credentials and use them to instantiate a service object:

https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

Comment: how to upload files programatically,how to use that service to upload file