# How to upload file or document in android GoogleDrive

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can i upload images, pdf documents or zip files in android google drive..
can you anyone suggest me:

MainActivity.class

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Button docs,images,music,share;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
     }
```

Comment: you should provide more code, so others can help you..

Comment: Already Answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402485/how-to-create-upload-file-to-google-drive-in-android-app

Comment: Try above link and also refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833358/how-to-upload-file-on-google-drive-using-my-android-application

Comment: ok..i tried all.but i didnt reach..any i ll try again